# Unidentified He's Dead Jim issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

This isn't isn't common with my code but one of the testers has found the issue in Chrome producing a 
"He's Dead Jim" in my section of old code. Ie/FF/Opera/safari can not replicate the issue in their own right. Currently able to replicate in Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 m (Most Recent todate). We use third party components through out the project, Kendo exclusively. And all of them are seen by the browser before reaching the part of the project where my piece is at (work flow wise). There are not any network related issues, (No 500s or 404s or 505s etc) JS console shows no issues. So i'm a little at odds when trying to diagnose and figure out the issue with this. Can anyone provide me anything else to attempt to test in trying to determine the cause of this? I have tested this with modifying the source code itself. The JS is fine, and whenever i remove the actual html (bootstrapped) it comes through fine.

If i remove this section of code it comes back without issues...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10" id="headerProp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.PropertyTypeId)<br />
                @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(a => a.PropertyTypeId).BindTo(Model.PropertyTypeList).DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }).Events(a => a.Change("changePropertyType").DataBound("changePropertyType"))
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.StatusOfProperty)<br />
                <select multiple id="StatusOfProperty" name="StatusOfProperty" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var PropertyTypes in Model.StatusOfProperty)
                    {
                        <option value="@PropertyTypes" selected="selected">@PropertyTypes</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Description)<br />
                @Html.TextAreaFor(i => i.Description, new { style = "width:100%; height:164px;", @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" id="photoImageForProperty">
        <img id="propImage" src="@Model.PropertyImage" style="width:100%;" alt="" />
        <input type="button" class="k-button" value="Add / View" onclick="showGallery()" style="width:100%" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.SerialNumber)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.SerialNumber, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.ModelNumber)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.ModelNumber, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.BrandName)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.BrandName, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.LocationRecovered, "Location Seized")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LocationRecovered, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MonataryValue)<br />
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.MonataryValue).Decimals(2).Format("c").Placeholder("$ 0.00").Max(Int16.MaxValue).Min(0).Spinners(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MonataryValueRecovered)<br />
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.MonataryValueRecovered).Decimals(2).Format("c").Placeholder("$ 0.00").Max(Int16.MaxValue).Min(0).Spinners(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">@Html.LabelFor(i => i.Weight)</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.Weight).Decimals(2).Placeholder("0.00").Max(Int16.MaxValue).Min(0).Spinners(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UnitofWeight, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Quantity)<br />
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.Quantity).Decimals(2).Placeholder("0.00").Spinners(false).Max(Int16.MaxValue).Min(0).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MasterEntityPersonId)<br />
        @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(i => i.MasterEntityPersonId).BindTo((IEnumerable<PropertyPersonViewModel>)ViewBag.casePeople).DataValueField("MasterpersonsEntityId").DataTextField("FullName").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control input-md" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Color)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Color)
    </div>
</div>
<div id="recoveredLocation">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span>Recovered From:</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.location.Street)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.location.Street, new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.location.AptSuite)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.location.AptSuite, new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.location.City)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.location.City, new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.location.State)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.location.State, new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.location.Zip)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.location.Zip, new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.location.County)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.location.County, new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.DateRecovered)
            @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(a => a.DateRecovered).Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Jurisdiction)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Jurisdiction, new { @class = "k-textbox form-control", onblur = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We use MVC 4, C#, Razor Syntax

Comment: What on earth does "He's Dead Jim" mean here? Does the browser literally show an alert with that text and a picture of DeForest Kelley?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1270364?hl=en

Comment: Yeah i really wish Chrome would find some better way to say these.. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1270364?hl=en

Comment: Well it's almost certainly nothing in your HTML that's doing it; it's a JavaScript problem. You've got an infinitely-recursive function, or something that's allocating too much memory.

Comment: I guess also its a memory issue: Can you check the memory usage of the corresponding process? P.S.: I love the humor of the Chrome-Dev's with the "He's Dead Jim" message...

Comment: Memory usage for the process that's running Chrome and the tab moved a little less than 1024 KB up when rendering that page... Using Process Explorer by SysInternals: Private memory from 91168 to 91169 , and Working Memory from: 143507 to 144705

Comment: Well i attached VS2013 to the process that is the tab and when ever it finaly did fail when rending the page i got this error back. Unhandled exception at 0x1080DB1A (chrome_child.dll) in chrome.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000002C. Looks like a memory leak to me. Is that what you all gather as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much trial and error i have found the culprit. At least in my case. For my kendo textboxes i was setting a max size. Instead of setting it so something like 999 billion i set it to Decimal.MaxValue and Int32.MaxValue. Chrome did not like this and issued a memory overflow. the two sections that had this in it were:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MonataryValue)<br />
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.MonataryValue).Decimals(2).Format("c").Placeholder("$ 0.00").Max(Decimal.MaxValue).Min(0).Spinners(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MonataryValueRecovered)<br />
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.MonataryValueRecovered).Decimals(2).Format("c").Placeholder("$ 0.00").Max(Decimal.MaxValue).Min(0).Spinners(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">@Html.LabelFor(i => i.Weight)</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.Weight).Decimals(2).Placeholder("0.00").Max(Decimal.MaxValue).Min(0).Spinners(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UnitofWeight, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Quantity)<br />
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(i => i.Quantity).Decimals(2).Placeholder("0.00").Spinners(false).Max(Int32.MaxValue).Min(0).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I have adjusted them to much smaller values and it comes through without issue, This may just be a kendo limitation.